# I have made a 50W solar mppt charge controller, but don't have a solar panel. What can I use to replicate this without a solar panel

Tags: dc-dc-converter, diy, solar-charge-controller

It's a 50w solar charge controller. I'm using an Arduino-based system with the ACS712 current sensor. What other inputs could I use to replicate the functioning of a solar panel to test the functionality of the circuit?

Comment: What JP314 says plus a series resistor.The resistor provides droop and the current source provides "steep rolloff" at high current. Even better curve shaping can be obtained with diodes, zeners , resistors and even transistors which turn on or off at different voltages..BUT a current limited voltage source and a series resistor should be good enough in many cases.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked. But actually you need to test your circuit with a solar panel eventually. Why not just buy one now? This is the best way. It would be ideal to have a light source capable of putting 1000 W/m^2, too, but maybe you can get by using the sun as a light source at first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its a nominal 12 V panel, use a lab power supply. Set the output voltage to ~ 16-18 V, and set a current limit. This current limit represents the solar illumination level. So if it's a 12W panel, set current limit at 1A (from 1A * 12V = 12W).

Comment: Thanks for the resposnse, but I don't have access to this lab supply, that is the primary issue I am facing. Is there any DIY solution to this, like maybe using a battery at the input?

Answer (score 0):

You could calibrate a PD to match a constant ratio of PV Voc (open circuit) then load the voltage at 72 % to 82% of Voc.  That be very close to the matched impedance Max power or V-MPT. Then regulate the battery charger output current by using the input voltage ratio using match the PD and also not exceed Battery V limits.